# Boolean check for whether a nullable string is null or blank in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a nullable string

```
data class Stam(val value: String? = null)

val result = Stam("result")

val hasValue = result.value?.isNotBlank()
```

I want `hasValue` to not be nullable, but to return a definitive `true` or `false`.

How do I get a value back that is not of type `Boolean?`?

Comment: Why would a non-blank string set `isNull` to `true`? If you meant the opposite, then kotlin already has an `isNullOrBlank` function.

Comment: @Michael bad name, i fixed

Comment: [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) detectors fired. Why are the values nullable in the first place? What are you trying to acheive by writing an extension function to check if they are null or blank?

Comment: I am forced to have those values nullable because they are json objects that get deserialized, if i dont have them nullable, sometimes it crashes because the object is not exactly what it was supposed to be

Comment: The question asked for an extension function, but the accepted answer doesn't provide one. I think the real question was "How do I check a nullable String is non-null and not blank?".

Comment: It does provide one, in my extension function i put the question marks as needed, it made me realize the issue was an extra question mark

Comment: The question said that you want to write a new extension function, but the solution was to use the existing `isNullOrBlank` function. So the accepted answer does not answer "How do i define an extension to do this for me?" but it does answer "How do I check a nullable String is non-null and not blank?".

Comment: @AdamMillerchip how about this?

Comment: I made some changes to try to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

`val hasValue = !result.value.isNullOrBlank`

Note that the "?" after value is missing. This works because the extension function isNullOrBlank itself is defined on `CharSequence?`

See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-blank.html

Comment: I needed to remove the question mark, thank you!